# 4.0 inch background images become double bigger after upgrade xCode to 5.0.1

Tags: xcode

When i running by 3.5 inch, game running well.
like this:
[image]

Before upgrade, running by 4.0 inch also good. 
code like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UIImage(iPhone5Extension)

+ (UIImage *)imageNamedWithiPhone5:(NSString *)name imageTyped:(NSString *)type;

@end

#import "UIImage+iPhone5.h"

@implementation  UIImage(iPhone5Extension)

+ (UIImage *)imageNamedWithiPhone5:(NSString *)name imageTyped:(NSString *)type
{
    NSString *imgName = nil;
    if ([type length]==0) {
        type = @"png";
    } else {
        type = type;
    }
    if (IS_IPHONE5) {
        imgName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-568h",name];
    } else {
        imgName = name;
    }

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imgName ofType:type];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
    return image;
}

@end
```

Then in ViewDidLoad :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.DefaultImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamedWithiPhone5: @"Title" imageTyped:@"png"];
}
```

However, i have a pictures for 3 types:
Title.png/Title@2x.png/Title-586h.png

But after i upgraded to latest xCode, ran by 3.5 inch is good, **BUT ran by 4.0 inch mode, the image became like this...**

[image]

Not sure what happened!!!
So how can i recover it (Also good in 4 inch mode?)

Thanks in advance!!!